# TypeScript subclass of Promise cannot be used as async function return value for ES6+

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

index.ts:

```
class MyPromise<T> extends Promise<T>{
}

async function testFn1(): MyPromise<void> {
    return new MyPromise(resolve => resolve());
}
```

Take the above code snippet as an example.
TypeScript gives the following compilation error when I set target to `ES6` or later, using `tsc --target es6 index.ts`.

```
error TS1064: The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type. Did you mean to write 'Promise<T>'?
```

However, there will be no compilation error if I use `tsc --target es5 index.ts` to compile.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

An `async function` will always return a native `Promise`. Defining a subclass doesn't change that. What your `testFn1` returns is a `Promise<MyPromise<void>>`.